# Azure Communication Services - Send Email not arriving

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

When I send my first email from Azure Communication Services (az communication email send) it accepts the send email request, returning a MessageId. When I query that MessageId using "az communication email status get" it seems stuck at "status": "OutForDelivery", and no message email arrives.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong kind of double quote when specifying the recipient:

--to "reciever mail”  (U+201D)

instead of :

--to "reciever mail" (U+0022)

which I guess became part of the address!

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me and i have used below process:

Used below command:

```
az communication email send --sender "rithwik@0573c903c.azurecomm.net" --subject "Important" --to "reciever mail" --text "Hello Rithwik, How are you" --connection-string "endpoint=https://rithcon.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=zabZ3yu3w=="
```

Output:

[image]

Then checked the status:

```
az communication email status get --message-id "431a86" --connection-string "endpoint=https://rithcon.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=zabZ3ywNYx73w=="
```

Output:

[image]

Now received mail as below:

[image]

So the problem you are facing is at receiving end(problem is with recipient's email server), so you need to check if its in spam, or  blocked. See id there is a filtering block. So the process is correct only the problem is with recipient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an email to a user using ACS you need to configure the below

- [Create ECS Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/create-email-communication-resource)
- [Create managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-azure-managed-domains)
- [Connect domain to ACS resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/connect-email-communication-resource)

Have you checked your inbox, junk or spam folders still you didn't find the sent email? then

I would suggest you to enable diagnostics logging for your Acs resource and query the **ACSEmailStatusUpdateOperational** logs (provides message and recipient level delivery status updates related to the Email service send mail requests) to check the status of the message

[image]

Refer to these documentations for more information about how to enable [diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/analytics/enable-logging) and also about different supported [email logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/analytics/logs/email-logs#resource-log-categories) in ACS

**Note** : MessageID will be the correlationId in this table.

If your message delievery status was showing as **OutForDevlivery** and you have checked all the folder and you did'nt receive email then email might in queued state.

I would suggest you to raise a support ticket and to understand why the Email not yet delivered.