# Azure function -Queue trigger and Azure Communication service - mail

Tags: c#, azure-functions, message-queue, azure-queues, queuetrigger

I'm working in Azure queue and Azure communication service.
I have a code to send and receive messages to Azure Queue. I'm using web-API to send the queue and receive it with the use of the Azure function(Queue Trigger). Also, have a code to send emails in the Azure communication service. what I'm trying to do is " I want to send the message I received in the queue as an email". I'm looking for some examples, not getting anything regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to send the message I received in the queue as an email".

If you want to send using Azure communication Services code you can use [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email?tabs=windows,connection-string&pivots=platform-azcli) or  by Coding, you can use [c#](https://mailtrap.io/blog/azure-send-email/). you can integrate the referred c# code into azure function queue trigger.

Alternatively for communication services, you can simply use Azure Logic apps for it and below is the design which is required:
[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

Or. You can also use Service bus queue(best is service bus queue) design like below:

[image]

For further you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161448/azure-communication-services-send-email-not-arriving)